# Grails - not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a few basic grails domain objects:

Task
User

Recently, I wanted to be able to assign tasks to multiple Users.  So I added this code to the Task.groovy class:

```
static hasMany = [users: User]

static mapping = {
    users joinTable: [name: 'task_user', column: 'user_id', key: 'task_id']
}
```

So a Task can now be assigned to multiple users using a join table - joining Task and User tables.  Now when I create a new Task, it's giving me the error message:

"not-null property references a null or transient value: blah.User.address"

In the generated join table "task_user" it only needs the user_id from the User object so I don't understand why it's complaining that other user fields are null.  The user object will always be present in the database.  I don't want to have to fully load each user in order to create a new Task. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with cascading.

I want the behavior where if a Task is deleted, the associated entry in the task_user join table should be deleted.  I "never" want the User object updated/deleted as a result of saving a Task. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you post some code that generates the error? It would help in giving a better answer. My first thought is that the User object you're referencing isn't an instantiated version of User (meaning it's only got an id set, in which case you'd get an error like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fix**

You need to use User.load(id) to get a reference to an user object.  load unlike get doesn't hit the database - it just creates a proxy which can be used in place of the User object. As long as only the id property is accessed - db is not accessed.

**Explanation for the error you are seeing**

In your code you created a new user object (transient) which is not connected to hibernate. To get it connected to hibernate you either need to save it or add the belongs_to attribute - both of these will try to update the row in the user table with every field set to null. If it was a new user object you were creating and wanted it to be saved automatically you would need to set the belongs_to (~ to cascade).

Comment: One more question, with the way I structured my mapping in my original post, if I have my collection of transient users in which the only non-null field is "id", and then I load the Users as I stated in my last comment and finally SAVE the task: myTask.save( failOnError:true); will I ever be in any danger of any of the Users being automatically updated due to cascading?  Or is that only if I add belongs_to in the User object?  The cascading rules are a bit complicated.  Thanks.

Comment: on the first question - where are you getting the Task from.  If it is a form input - I think there is a way to make grails do it automatically - bind the id in form to User.load.  Otherwise it is better to have it as a separate collection of user ids instead of setting it to Task.users.  On the second question - no if you load the object there is no chance of it getting updated automatically - the only case when it will get updated is if you set one of the properties - in which case the object will first be initialized from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the constraints on the User table recently?  I've seen those errors before, usually when I make a property not nullable after the schema's already been generated... I'm guessing if there's a null value already in the table for a property that's modified to be not-nullable the schema-update fails silently and you end up with errors like this.